# I need to call a Servlet when a button is Clicked without form submission

Tags: html, servlets

```
 <button><span>ButtonName</span></button>
```

I need to fire a request to a Servlet after clicking a button, like `ButtonName` here.
For some restriction I am unable to wrap it to a form submission or any other tag.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Java servlet? What about <a href="...."><span style="...">BUTTON-TEXT</span></a>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so, especially [ask], before posting your next question here.

Comment: this process does not support many inline css content such as hover. I designed a button with much effort. But just due to lack of knowing process I can not call my desired servlet from the button @Flocke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the `<button></button>` tag inside a `<a></a>` tag and mention `href` for the redirect url.

```
<a href="/someurl"><button>ButtonName</button></a>
```

But if you insist to use only `<button>` tag then you might find, there is no kind of attribute to tell a redirect url. You can see the available [HTML button tag attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp). Yes of course you could have do it using a form submit. But you are not using that.

But yes, there is one way left. You could use the HTML `onclick` event attribute.

```
<button onclick="window.location='some/redirect/url'">Click me</button>
```

You might have noticed `onclick` attribute takes and run javascript and get executed on the element click event. So there is plenty more options if you want to exploit javascript for this.

Comment: Thanks Brother. It works.